# Transfer the value from a kendo checkbox to another one

Tags: jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui

Hy! I want to get the value from a checkbox, and set another one with that value. I used jquery:`$('#CommercialName').val($('#CommercialName2').is(':checked'));`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
var isChecked = $('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
$('#checkbox2').prop('checked', isChecked);
```

Comment: Sorry I accidentally down voted... I will reverse my vote when SO allows me to.